# How to push values into an array and find their average

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to create a function which takes an array and returns the average of it. The `Id` argument is the html id that I've passed into the function.

I don't know why but I am getting an error:

> ```txt
> script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
>     at avgFinder (script.js:12:12)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (one.html:21:49)
> ```

```js
let array = [];

const addToarray = (id) => {
    return array.push(id);
};
    
const avgFinder = () => {
    let total = 0;
    let count = 0;
    array.forEach(item => {
        total += item;
        count++;
    });   
    console.log(total / count);
    return total / count;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="1" onclick="addToarray(1)">1</div>
    <div id="2" onclick="addToarray(2)">2</div>
    <div id="3" onclick="addToarray(3)">3</div>
    <div id="4" onclick="addToarray(4)">4</div>
    <div id="5" onclick="addToarray(5)">5</div>
    <div id="6" onclick="addToarray(6)">6</div>
    <div id="7" onclick="addToarray(7)">7</div>
    <div id="8" onclick="addToarray(8)">8</div>
    <div id="9" onclick="addToarray(9)">9</div>
    <div id="10" onclick="addToarray(10)">10</div>
    <button class="click" onclick="avgFinder()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like your `console.log` statement runs before adding any value to the array, it returns the results of `total / count` both are 0.

Comment: @ISAE mentioned that you are logging before anything is added. You might want to add the console.log to your `addToarray` function or a to new button.

Comment: `addToarray` and  `avgFinder` in the globalThis scope without a `const`... why?

Comment: `avgFinder = (arr) => {` ... see the `arr` argument? Where are you passing it?

Comment: I used your code to make a snippet that you can run. As you can see, there is no such error - and I added a `console.log` to your `avgFinder` (otherwise there is no actual visible effect of clicking the button to find the average), and it seems to work OK to me!

Comment: Robin was my original code working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous edits of this answer gave a solution that was less than idea. The following addresses those:

- No pollution of globalThis
- Does not mix functionality with markup
- Does not mix data with functionality

```js
// wrapping function to avoid poluting globalThis
(function(){

  // data-store for values
  let arr = [];

  // Loop over each button that has a data-id
  document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id]').forEach(ele => {

    // Add event listener: when clicked add the button's value to the array
    ele.addEventListener('click', () => arr.push(Number(ele.dataset.id)));
  });
 
  // Get a reference to the result element
  const averageEle = document.getElementById('result');

  // Add event listener for when the average button is clicked
  document
    .getElementById('avgFinder')
    .addEventListener('click', () => {

      // no values to average
      if (arr.length === 0) {
          averageEle.value = 0;

      // nothing to average 
      } else if (arr.length === 1) {
          averageEle.value = arr[0];

      } else {

        const sum = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur);
        const average = sum / arr.length;
        
        averageEle.value = average;
      }
    });
 
})();
```

```html
<button data-id="1" type="button">1</button>
<button data-id="2" type="button">2</button>
<button data-id="3" type="button">3</button>
<button data-id="4" type="button">4</button>
<button data-id="5" type="button">5</button>
<button data-id="6" type="button">6</button>
<button data-id="7" type="button">7</button>
<button data-id="8" type="button">8</button>
<button data-id="9" type="button">9</button>
<button data-id="10" type="button">10</button>
<button id="avgFinder" type="button">Calculate Avg</button><br>
Average: <input id="result" type="text" value="0" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `avgFinder = (arr) => {` expects an `arr` *Array*, instead you're passing... nothing.
Also, `let total = 0;` cannot be a hardcoded `0`. It should be your `array.length` instead.

Here's a fix with best practices:

- Avoid using inline HTML `on*` JS handlers. Use the proper [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) isnstead. JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file.
- Use [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store arbitrary data that can be used in JavaScript.
- Use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce an Array to Number.
- Avoid polluting the GlobalThis scope by using `window` or undeclared *variables*. Try always to use `const`, or `let` when a value is expected to be changed at a later time.

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);


// Task: Find average:

const elsDataId = els("[data-id]");
const elAvgFinder = el("#avgFinder");
const elItems = el("#items");
const elResult = el("#result");

let array = [];

const addToArray = (n) => {
  array.push(n);
  elResult.value = "";
  elItems.value = array;
};

const avgFinder = () => {
  const count = array.reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0);
  const avg = count / array.length;
  elItems.value = "";
  elResult.value = avg;
  array = [];
  return avg
}

elsDataId.forEach((elDataId) => {
  elDataId.addEventListener("click", () => addToArray(+elDataId.dataset.id));
});

elAvgFinder.addEventListener("click", avgFinder);
```

```html
<button data-id="1" type="button">1</button>
<button data-id="2" type="button">2</button>
<button data-id="3" type="button">3</button>
<button data-id="4" type="button">4</button>
<button data-id="5" type="button">5</button>
<button data-id="6" type="button">6</button>
<button data-id="7" type="button">7</button>
<button data-id="8" type="button">8</button>
<button data-id="9" type="button">9</button>
<button data-id="10" type="button">10</button>

<button id="avgFinder" type="button">Calculate Avg</button><br>
Items: <input id="items" type="text" readonly><br>
Average: <input id="result" type="text" readonly>
```